# Impersonating Windows Client on Server

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, client-server

I am trying to write a C# application that will impersonate a Client on a Server to do some LDAP request.

The Client send the duplicateToken to the Server and the server should use it to impersonate the Client.
On the Server side it does not work, getting the getLastWin32Eror : 203

Client and Server apps run currently on the same PC but in the future it will not be the case.

On the client :

```
 [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
 private static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken, int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr hNewToken);
 [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
 public static extern bool ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(IntPtr phToken);

 /// {...}
 IntPtr duplicateToken = IntPtr.Zero;
 IntPtr currentToken = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(TokenAccessLevels.Duplicate).Token;
 DuplicateToken(currentToken, 3, ref duplicateToken);
 //if I try ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(duplicateToken) here it works
 //Send the duplicateToken to the Server
```

On the Server :

```
 /// {...}
 //get the clientToken from the Client
 bool isValid = ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(duplicateToken);
 if (!isValid)
 {
     int winerr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error();
     int winerr2 = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
 }
```

The Server and client are not running in the same Thread. 
Do you know if I have to attach the Token to a new thread to impersonate ? Or is there a way to use this token to act as the client.

I only require Impersonate to send some LDAP request as this particular Impersonated User.

EDIT: I updated the code calling the ImpersonateLoggedOnUser Function to get the last error :

```
 [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
 public static extern bool ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(IntPtr phToken);
```

Now calling getLastWin32Eror returns error 6.

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: updated @BrianDesmond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed the IntPtr which represent the Handle to the server after having converting it has a String. 
This works on the client, but the Server running in another process can not use the TokenHandle...